# Windows Mobile 6.5 C# Development: Where to start?

Tags: windows, mobile, c#

Where would I start to develop applications for Windows Mobile 6.5 using C# language?

Answer (score 6):

The best place to start would be going to [Windows Mobile Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/bb250560)

There you will find tons of different resources, labs, hands-on etc.
In MSDN, you start in [Getting Started in Developing Applications for Windows Mobile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158662.aspx)

Some code samples can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158662.aspx)

Other than MSDN, the web is also full of resources, for example:

- [Development of WMA](http://www.packtpub.com/article/development-of-windows-mobile-applications-part1)
- [Microsoft Mobile Development Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623589) is also good, since lots of stuff applies to 6.x
- You might also want to consider [.NET Compact Framework 3.5 Data Driven Applications](https://www.packtpub.com/data-driven-applications-with-.net-compact-framework-3-5/book?utm_source=developingfor.net&utm_medium=bookrev&utm_content=blog&utm_campaign=mdb_003632) book
- [This blog](http://smartmobidevice.blogspot.com/search/label/Resources)

Have fun :)

Answer (score 3):

You could start with purchasing Visual Studio 2008. It contains the tools needed for developing on the mobile 6.x platform. The express editions sadly do not provide this functionality and Visual Studio 2010 is designed only for the Windows 7 mobile platform.

If you still need to learn C#, then pick up Visual Studio 2008 Express for C# first and buy a book. It will let you learn the basics of Win32 and C# code without spending too much money.

Comment: I am pretty confident in C# knowledge. Just wondering about SDK tools for the winmo6.5 Never used studio, only separate installations of C# and C++

Comment: There are differences between the .net and compact .net framework. If you are familiar with the standard, then you will know everything in the compact framework, it will just be important to note what is not available (only about 30% of the standard framework is included). See here for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2weec7k5.aspx

Answer (score 3):

SDK download is here: [Windows Mobile 6.5 Developer Tool Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=20686a1d-97a8-4f80-bc6a-ae010e085a6e)

Answer (score 1):

Download Visual Studio 2008 full edition for either trial (90 days) or full use, if you bought it previously but lost the CD, from http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/d/81d3f35e-fa03-485b-953b-ff952e402520/VS2008ProEdition90dayTrialENUX1435622.iso . If you have the CD, of course, you can just use the CD.

Then download the Windows Mobile 6.5 SDK from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6135 .

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Dev Env:

Start on Smart Device Application using VB/C++/C# using visual studio 2008.

[Smart Device Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t.aspx)

Database :

[SQL compact edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.)

Regards..

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend getting and reading the [Microsoft Mobile Development Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623589) (Amazon Link)

Answer (score 0):

**To Develope Windows mobile application in 6.x series,**

You should have the following requirements.

**Development IDE:**

```
Visual Studio 2005 or visual studio 2008(Recommented)
```

**Programming Knowledge:**

```
Microsoft Visual C++, Visual Basic, C#(Recommented due to object oriented, popular)
```

**Installation of Other Tools and Environment:**

```
Visual Studio 2008 for Development purpose

Microsoft windows mobile software development kit (aks Emulator to Test)

Windows Mobile Device Center (Recommented) or Active Sync (To Establish connection b/w 
host and emultor(Network, file system etc))

.Net FrameWork 3.5 or more (csc.exe) For Compilation of .net compact libarary

.Net Compact FrameWork(CAB File)

.Net SQL compact Framework (If your application uses database)
```

**Note:**

```
.Net Framework is differnet from .Net Compact Framework.

Use .Net Framework for compilation, .Net compact for library. because, .net compact
donot have compiler on its own.
```

**Downloading Links:**

All Microsoft related products available in the microsoft download center.
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download